# OpenLayers 3 Pop-up?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In OpenLayers 2 I was using the OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud object. Under OpenLayers 3, this object is apparently gone, so I have replicated the functionality using an overlay. One feature of the older style popup that I haven't been able to replicate however is the automatic positioning. That is, under OpenLayers 2 it would change where the pop-up opened relative to the map point depending on where it had the most room. So it might be above, below, to the right, or to the left of the point. How can I replicate this functionality in OpenLayers 3?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but [ol.Overlay](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html) takes an option `autoPan` which will pan the map so that the popup is visible.

```
  var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
    ...
    autoPan: true,
    autoPanAnimation: {
      duration: 250
    }
  });
```

http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/popup.html

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried that. It didn't work. That said, given that I am using a mouse hover selector, I can see the map moving when the popup appears as potentially causing issues with usability, so I'll just look into other options to manually calculate position.

Comment: @ibrewster [take a look](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-contextmenu) at how I calculate the best place to show a `contextmenu`.

Comment: @JonatasWalker: That should work pretty much perfectly. Thanks!